# Windows Phone 8.1 - Auto Complete and ListBox Focus

Tags: xaml, listbox, windows-phone-8.1

I have textbox and a listbox. On typing into textbox, listbox will start populate suggestions based on text typed in textbox. The Listbox is inside a popup and will open only if there are any suggestions. A traditional custom auto suggestion box.

Now the problem is, when user started typing, the popup will open and steal the focus from textbox. So user cannot continue typing. What is the best and standard approach to solve this problem?

I tried focusing the textbox, as soon as the popup opens. But still it has a small lag (for the first time, when ListBox rendered) and I could see a flickering with virtual keypad jumping up and down.

Comment: IsEnabled=False or IsTabStop=False or IsHitTestVisible=False on the ListBox

Comment: Have you considered using a ComboBox? It seems to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to stop the text box from losing focus...

I am assuming you are using MVVM(Model View ViewModel) for your list box and text box. So I would have a search criteria value in my view model populate the list in  the pop-up.

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SearchCriteria, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"></TextBox>
```

*UpdateSourceTrigger* is the key, by default text box only updates on lost focus  But when you change the binding to UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, it will update the view model on every key stroke.

This way you can re-filter the list with every key stroke and the text box will not lose focus.